# Question about a convex optimization using gradient descent

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Recently I have read a paper, but I was confused about the optimized method of this article. In the following I will try to abstract the problem in the text. Supposed that we have six variables $\bf{\theta_{1}},\bf{\theta_{2}},\bf{\theta_{3}}$,$w_1,w_2,w_3$,(note that $\bf{\theta}$ is a column vector and $w$ is a scalar) and a continuous and differentiable function $f(x)$. And here the variables satisfy the relationship
$$
\theta_{i}^{t+1} = \sum_{n=1}^{3}w_n\theta_{n}^{t}, i=1,2,3
$$
Here $t$ means a moment, and t = 0,1,2,...N. Besides, let's just think of $i$ as some fixed value. Our target is to find $w_1, w_2, w_3$ at each moment t which can minimize the following:
$$
\min_{w_1,w_2,w_3}f(\theta_i^{t+1})=\min_{w_1,w_2,w_3}f(\sum_{n=1}^{3}w_n\theta_{n}^{t})
$$
**In my opinion**, at the moment $t+1$, because $w_1,w_2,w_3$ are variables, and $\theta_1^t,\theta_2^t,\theta_3^t$ are constant vector, we can think that $\theta_i^{t+1}$ is a linear combination of $w_1,w_2,w_3$. To minimize $f(\theta_i^{t+1})$, using gradient descent method, we can find a appoximated solution $\tilde{\theta}_i^{t+1} $after T iterations:
$$
(\theta_i^{t+1})^{T+1} = (\theta_i^{t+1})^{T} - \eta\nabla_{(\theta_{i}^{t+1})^T} f((\theta_i^{t+1})^{T})
$$
Here $\eta$ is the step size. Using the chain rule, we have:
$$
\nabla_{(\theta_{i}^{t+1})^T} f((\theta_i^{t+1})^{T})=\frac{\partial f((\theta_i^{t+1})^{T}) }{\partial w_1}\cdot \frac{\partial w_1 }{\partial \theta_{i}^{t+1}} + \frac{\partial f((\theta_i^{t+1})^{T}) }{\partial w_2}\cdot \frac{\partial w_2 }{\partial \theta_{i}^{t+1}} + \frac{\partial f((\theta_i^{t+1})^{T}) }{\partial w_3}\cdot \frac{\partial w_3 }{\partial \theta_{i}^{t+1}}
$$
Let $\bf{w}$$=[w_1,w_2,w_3]^{H}$, here $H$ means transposition, then we have:
$$
\nabla_{(\theta_{i}^{t+1})^T} f((\theta_i^{t+1})^{T})=[\frac{\partial w_1 }{\partial \theta_{i}^{t+1}},\frac{\partial w_2 }{\partial \theta_{i}^{t+1}},\frac{\partial w_3 }{\partial \theta_{i}^{t+1}}]^{H} \nabla_{\bf{w}} f((\theta_i^{t+1})^{T})
$$
So, the final iteration formula should be
$$
(\theta_i^{t+1})^{T+1} = (\theta_i^{t+1})^{T} - \eta[\frac{\partial w_1 }{\partial \theta_{i}^{t+1}},\frac{\partial w_2 }{\partial \theta_{i}^{t+1}},\frac{\partial w_3 }{\partial \theta_{i}^{t+1}}]^{H} \nabla_{\bf{w}} f((\theta_i^{t+1})^{T})
$$
The above is my opinion. But in the paper it seems that the final result is
$$
(\theta_i^{t+1})^{T+1} = (\theta_i^{t+1})^{T} - \eta \bf{1}^{H} \nabla_{\bf{w}} f((\theta_i^{t+1})^{T})
$$
Here $\bf{1}$ is a size-3 vector of ones. By the way, it seems that the moment $t$ and iteration $T$ are mixed in the paper, and **the above is purely my personal understanding, I hope that someone can tell me what went wrong in my solution process?** If someone is interested in the paper, you can search "PERSONALIZED FEDERATED LEARNING WITH FIRST ORDER MODEL OPTIMIZATION", but I think it may be tough for you if you don't know about federated learning. Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of defining $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ if they are all the same?

Comment: This involes the background of federated learning, $\theta_i$ means the $i$ client model parameters.